# Excel c# convert cell to percentage

Tags: c#, excel, coding-style, range

I need to convert a cell with a double to a precentage.
I used a macro in excel and it says:

```
Range("B5").Select
Selection.Style = "Percent"
```

When I do this in c#, it doesn't work:

```
Excel.Range procentRange = xlWorksheet.get_Range("A1","A1");
procentRange.Style = "Percent";
```

Anybody knows how to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've found the anwser with help of JN Web

```
Excel.Range procentRange = xlWorksheet.get_Range("A1","A1");    
procentRange.NumberFormat = "###,##%";
```

So first you need a range, then set the decimals and add "%" -> automatically a 100 time multiplication

Comment: I didn't know what the actual percent format you were looking for was, glad that my mostly generic answer helped.

Comment: Accepting JN Web's answer would be fair rather than accepting yours. He showed the path and u walked. :P

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Excel.Range.NumberFormat` instead of `Excel.Range.Style`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Excel.Range.Style.NumberFormat.Format="#,###.00%"`

Answer (score -1):

Try this 
procentRange.NumberFormatLocal = "0.00%"