# In Excel 'Number stored as Text' because of % sign attached to the Double value like '80,00%' in C#

Tags: c#

I have a double value which I need to attach a percentage (%) sign to it like (80,00%). This gets written as a text in the Excel file due to my way of coding.

Here is the following code in C#.

```
var decimalValue = 80.0m;
(decimalValue / 100)?.ToString("#0.00%");
```

Output

```
80,00%
```

In Excel file I get a green issue mark which tells that the number is stored as text.

How to solve this issue buy storing the double value with the percentage as a 'number' so I won't get the green mark?

Comment: `%` is text. You want to save it as a number between 0 and 1, I suspect. You'll also need to set the right field type which won't be possible on a CSV, but is possible on an Excel file.

Comment: What file format are you using and are you using a library to write it?  If it's CSV then you don't have a lot of control, other than writing the double out as a floating point value in the output.  If xls or xlsx then what library are you using to write it?

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281809/converting-excel-cell-to-percentage-using-epplus

Answer (score 0):

That worked for my poc project:

[Excel c# convert cell to percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005015/excel-c-sharp-convert-cell-to-percentage)

I found the right solution for my project when we use Aspose cells to make workbook and worksheets:

```
var templatePath = @("C:\Temp");
var workbook = new Workbook(templatePath);
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
var decimalObject = 80.0m;
var convertedDecimalObject = (decimalObject / 100)?.ToString("#0.00%");
worksheet.Cells[0].PutValue(convertedDecimalObject, true);
```

The 'true' beside the converted decimal object tells that the object can be converted to other proper type in the excel file